# Query Synomys ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I create a new index with synonym in this way :

**PUT /test_index2**

```
{
"settings": {
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : [
                        "mezzo,centro"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

When i try this query :

```
{
   "query": 
     {
        "multi_match": 
            {
               "query": "centro",
               "fields": ["content"],
                "analyzer": "synonym"
            }
      }
  }
```

Kibana gives me this error :

```
  [multi_match] analyzer [synonym] not found
```

I'm not very experienced with elastic could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom analyzer that leverages your synonym filter

```
{
"settings": {
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer": {                          <-- add this
                "synonym_analyzer": {
                   "type": "custom",
                   "filter": ["synonym"],
                   "tokenizer": "keyword"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : [
                        "mezzo,centro"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it in your query

```
{
   "query": 
     {
        "multi_match": 
            {
               "query": "centro",
               "fields": ["content"],
                "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"   <-- change this
            }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Should I do the same thing if I use a txt?

Comment: not sure what you mean, the content field is a `text` field right?

Comment: insert synonyms in txt file, because i have more synonyms

Comment: then simply specify the path to the synonyms file and restart your nodes